# accessing index in callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, I have this NodeJS code:

```
for(var i = 0; i < subcats.length; i++) {

            subcats[i].getChallenges(function(challenges) {
                this.challenges = challenges;

                if(index == subcats.length - 1)
                    res.render('challenges/category', {'category': category, 'subcats': subcats});
            });

        }
```

The issue is that by the time getChallenges calls the function, the index is at its breaking point and I need to call res.render on only the last getChallenge callback. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!!!

Comment: Where are you defining `index` ?

Comment: I'd probably set it up as something like: http://jsfiddle.net/Ekm9G/ but you've left out a lot of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use index variable out of the functions scope and increment it in callbacks:

```
var completed = 0;
for(var i = 0, len = subcats.length; i < len; i++) {
  subcats[i].getChallenges(function(challenges) {
    this.challenges = challenges;

    if(++completed == len) {
      res.render('challenges/category', { 'category': category, 'subcats': subcats });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't think ofthis, sometimes simplicity gets the best of us...

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `i` in a closure:

```
(function(i) {

    // 'i' here is a copy -- 
    // it will keep the same value, even after the outer loop increments its own 'i'

    subcats[i].getChallenges(function(challenges) {
        this.challenges = challenges;

        if(index == subcats.length - 1)
            res.render('challenges/category', {'category': category, 'subcats': subcats});
    });

}(i));
```

This creates a local copy of `i` for each iteration, so that each callback will be bound to its corresponding `i`.

Comment: Thank you! I would give yours the answer but I think Maksims is better. I appreciate your time and thought though!